# How do I wrap a middleware in a function?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to restrict sriracha-admin to a certain IP.

So I'm doing:

```
var admin = require('sriracha-admin');
app.use("/sriracha-admin", admin({
    user:"user", 
    pass:"pass123"
  }) 
);
```

Can I do something like:

```
app.use("/sriracha-admin", function(){
  if(req.ip === 111.222.333.444){
    return admin({
      user:"user", 
      pass:"pass123"
    });
  }
});
```

Or perhaps I'm going about it totally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to not be lazy and read the docs and I found the answer in a matter of seconds.

Here it is if anyone is  looking for an answer on how to restrict a middleware by ip or by anything else.

```
var ip = '1234';
app.use("/admin", function(req, res, next){
    if(ip === '123'){
      next();
    }else{
      res.sendStatus(404)
    }
  },
  admin({
      username: "user",
      password: "pass"
  })
);
```

My very little understanding of Express was holding me back from writing the very simple above code and perhaps explaining my question well enough.
But in case someone is looking for anything similar, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know sriracha, but a quick look shows that the admin() function returns an Express app: https://github.com/hdngr/sriracha/blob/master/index.js#L104

Since middleware in Express looks like this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
  next();
});
```

(See an example here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

...my guess is that your example might be re-written:

```
app.use("/sriracha-admin", admin(myoptions).use(function(req, res, next){
  if(req.ip === 111.222.333.444){
    //throw an exception here, or redirect, or whatever
  });
});
```

Not sure I nailed the closing braces there but you get the idea hopefully.

Comment: I tried your recommendation but.. 1. it isn't working. I am able to access it regardless, I tried console logging, nothing is happening. 2. What if the middleware does not return an Express app? Or does a middleware always return an Express app?

Comment: Middleware is _used_ by an Express app to modify/manage the request pipeline. Sriracha returns an Express app, not middleware. So you should be able to inject your own middleware into the Sriracha middleware pipeline and modify the request.

Comment: I should be, according to what you are saying. But I am testing and nothing is happening.
Either if it's Sriracha or a totally different middleware, how do I restrict it to a certain condition?

Comment: Try attaching a debugger with VS Code or another good debugging environment. Set a breakpoint on the line where you're checking the IP address. If you take the time to learn such a tool it will pay off in spades.

Comment: Thank you. But all I was looking for is the act of not continuing the app cycle on a certain route with a certain condition. So I read the docs and figured that I can tack on two middlewares and just simply not let the cycle pass through to the next one if the condition isn't true. I hope this explains my initial question better.